# user function that concatenates select results

Tags: mysql, sql

I want two tables, `user` looks like

```
+----+------------------+
| id | username         |
+----+------------------+
|  1 | 1234567890123456 |
+----+------------------+
```

and `kit` looks like

```
+----+---------+--------+--------+-------------------------+
| id | creator |  name  | script |           tag           |
+----+---------+--------+--------+-------------------------+
|  1 |       1 | kitkit | long   | 1234567890123456/kitkit |
+----+---------+--------+--------+-------------------------+
```

The tag column should be auto-computed from the username of the creator and the name of the kit.

I will try to create a user function that generates tag

```
create function tagify(creator, name) returns varchar(33) select concat(username, '/', name) from user where id = creator;
```

doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

A MySQL function should look more like this:

```
create function tagify (
    in_creator varchar(255),
    in_name varchar(255)
) returns varchar(33)
begin
    return concat(in_creator, '/', in_name) ;
end;
```

Note:

- The parameters should have types.
- The function should have a `return` statement.
- It should not be referencing an underlying table (for this purpose).

Comment: the `in_` prefix is a recommended convention?

Comment: @minseong . . . You want something to distinguish parameters from columns in queries (although not needed for this particular function).  I use `in_` and `out_` for clarity.

Comment: how do I turn `in_creator` into the `username` from the `user` table using `in_creator` as the primary key?